# Navigation Bar app requirement for Play Store

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play, softkeys

I have an Android app that requires the Navigation Bar to work. How can I hide this app on the Play Store for users that have a device with hardware navigation keys?

Comment: What do you consider "hardware navigation keys" to be? If you are referring to HOME, BACK, and such, the system's navigation bar is automatically handled by the OS.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to HOME and BACK. My app specifically targets devices that don't have those buttons physically.

Comment: The OS already offers a navigation bar for devices that don't have those buttons physically.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am aware of that. My app demonstrates the [Immersive Mode](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive.html) that was introduced in Android 4.4. This mode hides, if present, the navigation bar. That is why my app targets those devices.

Comment: Immersive Mode hides both navigation and notification bars. So even on devices without navigation bar, immersive mode can be demonstrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no [`<uses-feature>` elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features) or [`<uses-configuration>` elements](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-configuration-element.html) that allow you to filter on the existence of off-screen affordances for HOME and back, at least that I can see.

Hence, other than manually identifying devices that you want to support, and manually limiting distribution to them in the Play Store, I do not see another way to handle your request.

The point behind something like immersive mode is for it to be used on *all* devices, albeit with differing effects depending on device characteristics.